# Android SDK Build tools does not create ID's

Tags: android, android-xml, r.java-file, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

When I try to add an id to my xml file the sdk build tools are not adding the id to the R.java file. I know my build tools are on the path because it was building the ids properly like an hour ago, but I restarted my comp to update VirtualBox for some other reason and now it doesn't work. So this is what I have for the xml

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/personjanedoe"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borders_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/earth" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person2_description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:text="Jane Doe" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here's what I have for the R.java file (I've hit save like a billion times still not building)

```
 public static final int messagesicon=0x7f060098;
    public static final int messagesview=0x7f060066;
    public static final int messagetext=0x7f060071;
    public static final int middle=0x7f060012;
    public static final int never=0x7f060009;
    public static final int none=0x7f060010;
    public static final int normal=0x7f060000;
    public static final int person1=0x7f06008e;
    public static final int person1_description=0x7f060089;
    public static final int person1_friendlistdescription=0x7f060064;
    public static final int person1profilepic=0x7f06007d;
    public static final int profileIdeology=0x7f06007b;
    public static final int profileOccupation=0x7f060079;
    public static final int profileParty=0x7f06007a;
    public static final int profileStates=0x7f060077;
    public static final int profilecity=0x7f060078;
    public static final int profilecountry=0x7f060076;
    public static final int profileemail=0x7f060075;
    public static final int profilename=0x7f060074;
    public static final int profileprofilepic=0x7f060073;
    public static final int profilesearchIdeology=0x7f060086;
```

it should be right there with all the other letter p id's but it's not. I first noticed this problem when I was trying to use findViewById and it was giving me a red squiggly line. Please help me this project is due tomorrow!!!!!

Comment: Are you using Android studio ( eclipse )? I assume so.

Do you have the "build automatically" selected , from eclipse if you are using it ?

Comment: where is this build automatically option? I always assumed that it was default selected

Comment: yeah just checked its selected

Comment: Try cleaning up your resource, You can delete the R.java and try clean and build again it may just solve it. Eclipse acts weird sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't edit your R.java because it is AUTO GENERATED!

Change your all `android:id` and then build your project one more time but if you are using Eclipse your problem might be related with it I think you should restart your IDE.

Comment: I'm not manually editing R.java I know that's suicidally dumb, I'm just showing it to show that the id's I want are not being generated. But I'll try restarting eclipse.

Comment: ok now I'm getting a running android Lint error. Any idea what might be up?

Comment: your text should be like:android:text="@string/xxx" so you're facing this lint error.Lint just recommend to use @String notation but you can continue as u wrote

Comment: oh yeah well I don't really care about using softcoded strings in some places so I ain't gonna change that